# Block video calls with Mikrotik

Tags: networking, skype, mikrotik-routeros

I have created a simple firewall filter rule on Mikrotik router to disable internet access on certain ip addresses at a certain time. Everything works fine, but if the user is currently on a video call such as Skype or MS Teams and the rule kicks in, the user is not disconnected and is able to proceed with the video call. I would like the rule to disable anything to do with internet which also includes terminating any active video calls etc. The rule I used is the following:

```
add action=drop chain=forward comment="Disable Internet by time" src-address-list="!Allow Lan" time=23h-5h,sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is already in the state table, and therefore it's not checked against the firewall rule list. That's what allows the existing connections to continue.

What you would have to do is drop connections from the state table, or reset all of them. I'm not sure how this works on Mikrotik, a quick google yielded the following:

```
:foreach i in=[/ip firewall connection find] do={/ip firewall connection remove $i}
```

Comment: This is more commonly written as `/ip firewall connection remove [find]`.